# Gamebreaking Glitch in Borderlands 2

Tags: borderlands-2

I'm using a Siren character. I'm in the mission "A Dam Fine Rescue" and my objective is to get bandit car parts. I destroyed one of the cars and the part flew off the map. I restarted the game but the only way to progress is to get the part, but I will be automatically killed if I try to get out of the map.

Comment: Quitting out and continuing the campaign still had the part off the edge?  I find that surprising.  I feel like I had this happen before, and more vehicles would spawn anyway (it has been a while, could be remembering wrong).  But to clarify, when you quit out and continue your campaign, the vehicle part is off the map and no more vehicles are spawning?  Correct?

Comment: @PawnInGameOfLife Yes, Correct. I'll play every so often to see if they respawn.

Comment: This thread suggests you might need to leave the zone completely, quit the game, restart and then come back: http://oldforums.gearboxsoftware.com/oldforums/20150310045311/http://oldforums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=152151

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leaving into a different map then quitting & restarting the game will respawn the enemies so you can come back and do it again.